# Understanding the definition of Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

This is the definition I was given of Lie bracket:

Let be $M$ a differentiable manifold and $v$ and $w$ two vector fields on $M$. The Poisson bracket $[v,w]$ between $v$ and $w$ is a vector field on $M$ defined in this way:
$$[v,w]_x (f_x)=v(w(f_x))-w(v(f_x))$$
for every $f_x \in C_x^\infty (M)$ space of germs at the point $x\in M$.

I interprete this definition in this way:

I have that $$[v,w]_x:f_x\in C_x^\infty(M) \mapsto[v,w]_x(f_x)\in \mathbb{R}$$
where $$[v,w]_x(f_x)=v_x(w(f_x))-w_x(v(f_x)).$$
Here I have problems in understanding what is $w(f_x)$.
Since $v_x$ is an element of  the tangent space at $x$ I have that $w(f_x)\in C_x^\infty$. Now I think that this germ is the equivalence class associated  to the function $$y\in U_x \mapsto w_y(f_y).$$

Is my interpretation correct? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. This is the *Lie bracket* of the vector fields. Poisson bracket refers to an operation on *functions* on a symplectic manifold. Your germ notation gets a little awkward, but, yes, your interpretation is correct. Vector fields act (even on germs) by directional derivatives.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you!